# Share a pie game [Game theory]

Tags: game-theory

I consider the following game : three players have a pie to share. Player 1 proposes a division and then simultaneously player 2 and 3 respond either yes or no.

Each player prefer to have more than less share and the payoff of each player is the corresponding share that is adopted.

This game can be naturally represented by a tree (extensive form game).

I would like to find the subgame perfect equilibrium using the usual backward induction.

The tree is as follows : player 1 proposes a triplet $(x,y,z)\in[0,1]^3$ (res presenting the share of each player starting from player 1 to player 3), then player $2$ responds yes or no and then player $3$ responds yes or no.

For player $3$ to accept we need to have $z>0$ and for player $2$ to accept we need to have $y>0$.

Then, for player $1$ the choice is more difficult I find. Propose $(x,y,z)$ with each component strictly positive seems to be the « natural choice » however how to define precisely the quantity ?

The fact that each player prefer to have more share than less (especially the first player, which chooses the quantity) make me doubt about finding a subgame perfect equilibrium of the form $\{ (x,y,z),\text{yes},\text{yes}\}$ with $x,y$ and $z$ strictly positive.

I would like to have your help on this question please.

Thank you a lot

---

Some precision :
For the  proposition of share of the player 1 to be adopted, we need to have the agreement of player 2 and 3, otherwise the share is not adopted and everybody get $0$.

Comment: I suppose we have a constraint x+y+z=1. If Player 1 proposes (0.999999, 0.0000005, 0.0000005), players 2 and 3 will accept, and player 1 would be happy.

Comment: Yes there is this constraint thank you. Thank you for your proposition, however there is a deviation possible for player 1 : propose $(0.9999999, 0.00000005,0.00000005)$ and we can pursue like this again and again…so it is not a subgame perfect equilibrium.

Comment: Why do you think players 2 and 3 will vote yes as long as they get anything at all? And what does it take for a proposition to pass? Is two players accepting sufficient (i.e., if either 2 or 3 accepts, it passes) or all three players needed (it is accepted only if 2 and 3 both accept)? We also need to know what happens if it isn't accepted. Does the whole thing fail, and nobody gets anything? Does Player 1 keep trying until it is accepted? Does another player propose? What if they never agree? Does that count as not getting anything?

Comment: With player 1 continually proposing, all three players needing to agree, and failure to eventually agree means getting nothing, then $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ will be an equlibrium.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your comment, I added some precision answering your questions I think. Concerning the equilibrium I proposed, it is in the sense of Nash equilibrium and it is not the only one I think.

Comment: There is no equilibrium in a single proposition game. Player 1 has to provide a little to each of 2 and 3 to get their vote, but there is nothing that pushes back against player 1 making their pieces smaller. So no matter what player 1 proposes, they could have proposed something else that would have been better. And I mean no equilibrium by any definition, even Nash.

Comment: The reason why you get an equilibrium in the repeated proposal scenario is that it gives power to 2 and 3 to push back against player 1. If they are unhappy with their proportion, they can vote no, knowing that player 1 must increase it or will get nothing. But they also know that player 1 can refuse to increase it and then they will get nothing either, so they also have an incentive to not get greedy. It is that playoffs of interests that results in equilibriums.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  However I am not sure of what you said, player 1 is the only to propose a sharing, the others only approve or not the sharing so I do not understand the sentence « they could have proposed something else that would have been better », who are the « they » ?

Comment: Using gendered pronouns is a minefield these days, even in the most innocent of circumstances, so I avoid it because I don't want to deal with the garbage. "they" refers to the person currently under discussion: Player 1.

Comment: Okay thank you I understand ! Now, if I take the strategy $\{(1,0,0), no, no\}$ for example, each player has no deviation given the strategy of the others, why it is not a Nash equilibrium ? In the sense that at fixed strategy of player $i,j$, the player $k\neq i,j$ is not able to change increase its payoff

Comment: It is hard to read your messed up comment (you have 5 minutes to fix it). But how is $(1,0,0)$ an equilibrium? Player 1 can improve their result by almost any other proposal.

Comment: Yes sorry I tried to make it clear. Yes but we consider here Nash equilibrium so the strategy of other players are fixed when we are looking for a deviation of one player